# emacsclient closes immediately on "*ERROR*: Beginning of buffer"

Tags: emacsclient, error

I have an app where I call emacsclient to do some editing on an org file.  When it calls it, the frame flashes for an instant, then closes immediately.  On stderr, I get the following message:

```
*ERROR*: Beginning of buffer
```

Apparently, something is trying to move the cursor up when it is at the beginning of the buffer, signals an error, then closes the frame.  I am trying to figure out what is doing this.  My first thought was that it was the "find-file-hook" or the "org-mode-hook" but even after setting these nil, I get the same behaviour.  Setting 'debug-on-error' does not produce a stack trace.

Any suggestions for how to diagnose this?

### Additional Information

I tried getting the debugger to come up by evaluating the following elisp inside the host emacs:

```lisp
;; Setup diagnosis of errors from emacsclient
(defun ded:bugon ()
  ;; Remove the normal value of beginning-of-buffer from list
  (setq debug-ignored-errors
        '(beginning-of-line end-of-line end-of-buffer
                            end-of-file buffer-read-only
                            file-supersession mark-inactive
                            user-error))
  (setq debug-on-error t))
(ded:bugon)
```

No success: the debugger does not get triggered.  Also, per @NickD, I ran the command from the shell and got the same problem, except that once in every 20-30 attempts, it works.  Really puzzled.

Per @NickD, here is the command being called:

```sh
$ emacsclient -a='' -c /home/ded/byr/tmp/registertransacts20220125-185348-smeoi7.org
Waiting for Emacs...

*ERROR*: Beginning of buffer
⏎
```

Of course, the temporary file name changes, but it always follows that pattern.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem doing the `emacsclient <whatever>` by hand at a shell?

Comment: Yes.  It happens when I execute the same command from the shell.

Comment: Weird. What does the command look like? Can you show an example?

Comment: @NickD, I added the command being called to the question.  So much easier than formatting a comment.  Also, I should clarify, the intermittent working happens from both the command line and when called from the program.

Comment: Have you taken a look at some of these temporary files? Are they legal Org mode files? Can you try running `org-lint` on a couple? Is there anything fishy in the `find-file-hook` or the `org-mode-hook`? Can you try with a minimal environment, stripping out most, if not all, of your init file?

Comment: @NickD, all files report no problems with org-lint.  They are all org-tables with a #+NAME: property at the top.  When I set the hooks you nentioned to nil, it still happened, as well as with any other hooks I couls think of.  You may be right, I may just have to try to bisect my init to see what's going on.  Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Hope you finger the culprit!